# Node-Sass will not compile/transpile @use "module"

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass, node-sass

I´m trying to transpile/compile the following example provided by [https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#load-paths]

```
// src/_corners.scss
$radius: 3px;

@mixin rounded {
  border-radius: $radius;
}

// style.scss
@use "src/corners";

.button {
  @include corners.rounded;
  padding: 5px + corners.$radius;
}
```

this is the error that node-sass gives me:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "C:/Users/path/scss_mixins/style.scss",
  "line": 4,
  "column": 12,
  "message": "Invalid CSS after \"  @include corners\": expected \"}\", was \".rounded;\"",
  "formatted": "Error: Invalid CSS after \"  @include corners\": expected \"}\", was \".rounded;\"\n        on line 4 of style.scss\n>>   @include corners.rounded;\r\n   -----------^\n"
}
```

this is my cli input:

```
npx node-sass -o ./dist style.scss
```

node, npm and node-sass are all up to dates versions.

Thanks for help in advance. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found out that node-sass based in libsass is currently not supporting the

```
@use "module";
```

feature.

I got it to work with [dart´s sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) for node.